# int variable not initialized

Tags: java, variables

```
private int getBirthdayYear(){
        Random r1 = new Random();
        int x = r1.nextInt(1000);
        int year = 1000+ x;
        return birthdayYear;
      }
          private String getBirthday(){
        int year = getBirthdayYear();
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int y = r2.nextInt(11);
        String monthStr;
        int month = 1 + y;
          switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthStr = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthStr = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthStr = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthStr = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthStr = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthStr = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthStr = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthStr = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthStr = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthStr = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthStr = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthStr = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthStr = "Invalid";
                     break;
        }


        Random r3 = new Random();
        **int day;// day variable declared as int**
        if(month == 1||month == 3||month == 5||month == 7||month == 8||month == 10||month == 12){
        int z1 = r3.nextInt(30);
        day = 1 + z1;
        }
        else if(month == 2||month == 4||month == 6||month == 9||month == 11){
          int z2 = r3.nextInt(29);
        day = 1 + z2;
        }
        else if(month == 2 & year%4 ==0){
        int z3 = r3.nextInt(28);
        day = 1 + z3;
        }
        else if(month == 2 & year%4 != 0){
        int z4 = r3.nextInt(27);
        day = 1 + z4;
        }

        **birthday = monthStr + " " + day + "th " + year;// error here. day variable is not initialized
        return birthday;**
          }
```

This is a code for generating a random birthdate, I'm not sure yet if it works. I'm still working on it. Right now, when I try to compile this code, it says that the day variable is not initialized yet. However, I already stated int day;. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: -1 [Search for error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%22variable+might+not+have+been+initialized%22) - it is pretty common and occurs because a local variable (which has no default value) *must be assigned a value* along every possible execution path leading up to where it is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can't use a variable that might be uninitialized. "Uninitialized" means the variable might not have been set to anything. If the compiler cannot prove that the variable is always initialized, it will produce an error.

```
int a;

// a is uninitialized

if(r.nextInt(10) < 2)
   a = 5;

// a has an 80% chance of still being uninitialized

System.out.println(a); // error: a might not be initialized.
```

In your case:

```
int day;
// day is uninitialized
if(month == 1||month == 3||...){
    int z1 = r3.nextInt(30);
    day = 1 + z1;
}
else if(month == 2||month == 4||month == 6||month == 9||month == 11){
    int z2 = r3.nextInt(29);
    day = 1 + z2;
}
else if(month == 2 & year%4 ==0){
    int z3 = r3.nextInt(28);
    day = 1 + z3;
}
else if(month == 2 & year%4 != 0){
    int z4 = r3.nextInt(27);
    day = 1 + z4;
}
// if the month wasn't between 1 and 12, day is still uninitialized
```

The compiler is not smart enough to detect that `month` is always between 1 and 12.
The fix is to make sure `day` is always set to something, even if `month` is not in that range.

One way to do this:

```
int day;
// day is uninitialized
if(month == 1||month == 3||...){
    int z1 = r3.nextInt(30);
    day = 1 + z1;
}
else if(month == 2||month == 4||month == 6||month == 9||month == 11){
    int z2 = r3.nextInt(29);
    day = 1 + z2;
}
else if(month == 2 & year%4 ==0){
    int z3 = r3.nextInt(28);
    day = 1 + z3;
}
else if(month == 2 & year%4 != 0){
    int z4 = r3.nextInt(27);
    day = 1 + z4;
}
// THIS PART IS NEW
else
    day = -1; // this line will never actually run
```

Now the compiler can tell that, no matter what happens, `day` is always set to something after that if statement finishes.

Note that `day = -1;` never actually runs. It is only there so the compiler can prove that `day` always has a value.

Another way to fix the error is to change `int day;` to `int day = -1;` - for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

because you assign the value to day in the if-else block,but you didn't have a else block. so when all the condition in the if-else is not fit, the day is not initialized.
you need add a else block:

```
else {
    day = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here :

(1). 
**int day;// day variable declared as int**

Whenever you declare a variable . Initialize it with some value.
As my fellow scholar said,

```
int day=-1;
```

should be appropriate.

(2).
In,

```
private int getBirthdayYear()
 {
    Random r1 = new Random();
    int x = r1.nextInt(1000);
    int year = 1000+ x;
    return birthdayYear;
  }
```

Here, I am not sure why the calculation is being performed on the variable'year' when you are
return another variable 'birthdayYear'(Which I am assuming as a global variable) from the function.
You should return 'year' from there I suppose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the other mistake, I cut and pasted the lines and did not realize that I have to change the variable year to birthdayYear.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared it, but you haven't initialized int. Initializing it would look something like this:

```
int day = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to initialize day before just defining it, ie:

```
int day = -1;
```

I think that Java doesn't know if you are initializing the variable or if it is just lying around, without any value before you add it to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

A local variable (variable in a method) isn't initialized by default, so by typing:

```
int day; //day doesn`t have a value here
```

doesn't set a default value for `day`. If `day` were an instance variable (read a class variable) it would be set the default value of `0`, so, inside a method initialize the variable previously to use it:

```
int day = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assign values to `day` inside `if` and `else if` constructs.  If they all happen to be `false` the variable will not get any value.

`int day;` is just a declaration. To initialize it as well you can have `int day = 0;`.

Alternatively you can have `else` at the end of your `if` and assign a value to `day` there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should provide a default value to day with something like `int day = 1`. Second, you can check how many days a given month/year has with a `java.util.Calendar` like so -

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, month-1); // [... ] JANUARY which is 0.
int maxDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're initializing `day` with logic that has no *else* condition.

Consider the following obvious example:

```
int initMe;

boolean willInit = false;

if (willInit) {
    initMe = 1;
}

System.out.println("initMe is " + initMe);
```

Clearly this will not work because `initMe` will not be initialized in that logic. The solution is either to initialize it to a default value:

```
int initMe = -1;
```

Or give the conditions an else statement:

```
if (willInit) {
    initMe = 1;
} else {
    initMe = -1;
}
```

Either solution will work. For your situation (where your conditionals appear to be deciding how many days are in the month) you might either have an else for an error situation or refactor so else is a "default":

```
if (/* is February */) {
    if (/* is a leap year */) {

    } else {
        /* it's not a leap year */
    }
} else if (/* month has 31 days */) {

} else {
    /* presume it has 30 */
}
```

As a side note, I noticed it looks like you are trying to "cap" the input values with the [Scanner#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29) method but I don't think this will give you the results you are expecting. The int parameter is actually a radix argument. So something like `nextInt(28)` actually specifies that the input should be interpreted as a *base 28* number. Were you to enter in, say "15", the Scanner will actually return an integer with the value of 33.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i; // Declaration
i = 0; // Initialization
int i = 0; // Declaration + Initialization
```