# Return 3 integers that have the same difference between each two from smallest to biggest in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So, I wanted to insert an array of numbers, and return 3 numbers in order **biggest to smallest** with the same difference between each two.

#### Example:

```
2 3 7 9 12.
```

#### Return:

```
2 7 12 because 2+5=7, 7+5=12.
```

The code below is my attempt. I made 3 ***`for` loops***.

### Loops:

- The **first** went through the entire array, picked a number.
- The **second**: for the remaining numbers, picked a smaller number. Calculate their difference.
- The **third**: finds a third number that is smaller and has that same difference vs. the second number.

So: `(first number - second number) = (second number - third number)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int dif;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to choose from? ");
    n = scan.nextInt();
    
    int nums[] = new int[n];
        
    System.out.println("Please input the integers: ");

    for (int i=0; i<n ;i++){
        nums[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println(" ");
    
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++){      //compare element i to the rest of the array
            
            if(nums[j]<= nums[i]){  //if a num at j is smaller than num at i,
                num3 = nums[i];     //then num3 is num at i
                num2 = nums[j];     //and num2 is num at j
                dif = num3 - num2;  //find the difference
                
                for(int k=i+j+1; k<n; k++){ 
                    if(num2 == (nums[k]+ dif)){ //if num2 is num at k + difference
                    num1 = nums[k];             //then num1 must be num at k
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(num3); //This is the effort printing them out
    System.out.print(num2); //But for some reason I couldn't
    System.out.print(num1); //even I initialized num3,2,1 outside of the for loop
    
    scan.close();   //closing the scanner object
}
```

Comment: You need to sort the array first.

Comment: May I ask why would I need to sort the array ?

Comment: @HumbleHermit You wrote in your post that 7+5=14. I actually learnt in school that 7+5=12.

Comment: @HumbleHermit: Since you need iterate whole array and find differences in several STEPS (say start from 1 to n, at your example step=5) and find if 3 consequent members are exactly far apart from each other equal to your step, you need the array sorted to scan with increasing STEPS.

Comment: Oh shoot. 
Sorry Java Guy next door, I didn't sleep last night so I think I didn't feel very well then :(

Comment: I see. I will do that. Then what do I need to do next? @Xaqron

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. Does your code work? If not, does it give an error or does it give the incorrect output (and what is that error / output)? Based on the comments in the code I assume you're getting an error saying num1-3 may not be initialised, so you need to initialise them (assign values to them before the for-loop) ([it's easy to find that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307957/int-variable-not-initialized)).

Comment: @HumbleHermit: Next you need scan whole array with different arrays to find out if there are 3 consequent numbers with exact difference equal to the STEP. Than means you need two nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with two fors, if you are looking for faster one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 9, 17);
    Map<String, Integer> differenceMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        int first = integers.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < integers.size(); j++) {
            int second = integers.get(j);

            int difference = second - first;
            int next = difference + second;
            if (integers.contains(next)) {
                differenceMap.put(first + " - " + second + " - " + next, difference);
            }
        }
    }

    differenceMap.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);

}
```